# What did English use before "triangle"?

Tags: terminology, history, old-english, middle-english

Apparently the word "triangle" was [borrowed into English](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=triangle&allowed_in_frame=0) in the late 1300s.  Triangles are a very common shape in everyday life, and there were certainly English-speaking craftsmen and artists before the 1300s who would have needed a word for them.

What did English call triangles before they borrowed the word "triangle"?

Answer (score 9):

***[Gore](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gore)*** was used in OE to convey the idea of a triangle:

> - "triangular piece of ground," Old English gara "corner, point of land, cape, promontory," from Proto-Germanic *gaizon- (cognates: Old Frisian gare "a gore of cloth; a garment," Dutch geer, German gehre "a wedge, a gore"), from PIE *ghaiso- "a stick, spear" (see gar). ***The connecting sense is "triangularity." Hence also the senses "front of a skirt" (mid-13c.), and "triangular piece of cloth" (early 14c.).***

(Etymonline)

Comment: But the dates on this word are the same as the dates on OP's *triangle* (14c., 13c.)  Perhaps you meant to showcase *gara* (OE)?

Answer (score 9):

In Old English, the adjective ***þryscyte*** 'triangular' (Icelandic *þriskeyta* n. 'triangle') was used to define triangular shapes. Additionally, ***gar~gara*** suggests triangularity but it was only used for land masses and it is not always translated as a triangular land mass.

Here is a dictionary entry for *þryscyte* from *[An Anglo-Saxon Dictionary by Bosworth and Toller (1898)](http://lexicon.ff.cuni.cz/html/oe_bosworthtoller/b1070.html)*:

> **þri-scíte**; *adj. Triangular*, *three-cornered* :-- Ispania land is þryscýte *Hispania trigona est*, Ors. 1, 1; Swt. 24, 1. Sicilia is ðryscýte *Sicilia tria habet promontoria*, Swt. 28, 2. On ðone þryscýtan crundel, Cod. Dip. Kmbl. v. 374, 26. [Cf. *Icel.* þrí-skeyta a *triangle*.]

Here is an excerpt from the book G*rammaticalization at Work: Studies of Long-term Developments in English* (edited by Matti Rissanen, Merja Kytö, Kirsi Heikkonen) where you can see the translation of both Old English words:

[image]

*Note:* You can see the original text in *[archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/kingalfredsorosi79oros#page/24/mode/2up/search/garena)* also.

You can read much more details about geometric terms in Old English in the book *[Folk-taxonomies in Early English](https://books.google.ca/books?id=rYT8MPFl_egC&pg=PA272&dq=Pryscyte&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwia_NbcnvPKAhVHox4KHbmmCJ0Q6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=Pryscyte&f=false)* (By Earl R. Anderson) which also includes the following explanations:

> Although Anglo-Saxon and medieval societies were "carpentered worlds", Old English had basic terms only for curvilinearity (*hring* and *beag*), and until the fourteenth century Middle English had only *circul~circle* and *ring*.
>
> ...
>
> Like other Indo-European languages, Old English has no taxonym for 'geometric shape'; OE *hiw* (Gothic *hiwi*) usually means 'appearance'.
>
> ...
>
> Because of the paucity of geometric terms in Old English, buildings in poetry may be described in terms of their height and magnitude, but rarely in terms of shape.